# Time Difference in PostgreSQL

Tags: datetime, postgresql-9.2

I need to get a time which is exactly 1 hour earlier from the current time in PostgreSQL.

For example, if currently the time is 15:01:06, then I want the result to be 14:01:06.

How can I achieve this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work

select now()-interval '1 hour';